# tooltipster dynamic content does not work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, tooltipster

i'm very frustrated, because i can't find the answer how can i show tooltip with ajax dinamic content. If i use static contet it works, but it doesn7t work with dinamic contect. Can you please help me?

Here is my tooltipster script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.pomoctools').tooltipster({
        multiple: true,
        content: 'Loading...',
        functionBefore: function (origin, continueTooltip) {
            continueTooltip();
            // next, we want to check if our data has already been cached
            //if (origin.data('ajax') !== 'cached') {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'person/index_person_test.php',
                success: function (data) {
                    // update our tooltip content with our returned data and cache it
                    origin.tooltipster('content', $(data)).data('ajax', 'cached');
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Then I have this php page (here is just the code for displaying the data of person: person/index_person_test.php) :

```
$person_id = $_GET['person_id'];//person id

//find person's data
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM person WHERE person_id='$person_id'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$titleText = stripslashes($row[person_name]);

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT user FROM `users` WHERE id='$row[user_id_updt]'");
$user_name_updt = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

echo $person_id;
```

I want to show the tooltipster on my other php page, let's call it cast.php, here is just the part for tooltipster:

```
 echo '</td>

    <td width="100%" valign="top"><a href="?main=person/index&person_id='.$row[person_id].'&role=1" class="pomoctools" id="This is my links tooltip message!">'.$row[person_name].'</a></div>';
```

So my problem is that the toltipster does not show data when hovering on the link in cast.php.

If i change in person_index_test.php to:

```
$person_id = $_POST['person_id']; //person id
```

it does not help.

If i go to "**person/index_person_test**&person_id=56774"
the data is displayed correctly and if i echo the person id, i get the correct value:

```
echo $person_id;
```

I know i need to change things in javacript to fetch my mysql data correctly, but i can't find the answer. I have tried also adding to my jaascript after

```
url: 'person/index_person_test.php',
data: person_id,
```

or

```
data: 'person_id'
```

or

```
data: { 'person_id': person_id},
```

I have tried everything but it doesn't work.

If i cange in my javascript to static person_id then the tooltipster shows the content, but of course on hover the data is always the same. So for static i have changed this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '**?main=person/index_person_test&person_id=56774**',
    success: function(data) {
```

would you please help me? I have read all the tooltipster questions here on ostackoverflow, but i can't find the answer...

Thanks! Misko

Comment: could you please reduce your code so that we can feel easy to answer you.

Comment: ihave reduced it, thanks for advice, this is my first post!